# VBA Loop through row until blank and variable use

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is a web page table scraper that I am using and it works nicely. It currently only opens the hyperlink that is in location 'L4' using `.Open "GET", Range("L4"), False`

```
Sub ImportData()

'Objects
Dim htm As Object
Dim Tr As Object
Dim Td As Object
Dim Tab1 As Object

'Create HTMLFile Object
Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object

On Error GoTo Error

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", Range("L4"), False 'Cell that contains hyperlink
    .send
    HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

On Error GoTo Error

'Add New Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "ESTIMATE"

'Set table variables
Column_Num_To_Start = 1
iRow = 2
iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
iTable = 0

'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format
For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")
    With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
        For Each Tr In .Rows
            For Each Td In Tr.Cells
                Sheets(2).Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
                Sheets(2).Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText
                iCol = iCol + 1
            Next Td
            iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Next Tr
    End With
    iTable = iTable + 1
    iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next Tab1
 'Success

'Loop to find authorised hours string
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = "Hours"
Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
'Add Value to Sheet1

Sheets(1).Range("E4").Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
Else

Sheets(1).Range("E4").Value = 0
End If

strSearch = "Actual Hours"
Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
Sheets(1).Range("D4").Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
Else
  Sheets(1).Range("D4").Value = 0
'Move on to next
End If

strSearch = "Name"
Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
Sheets(1).Range("J4").Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1)
Else

Sheets(1).Range("J4").Value = "NULL"
End If

'Scrape Description
Dim desc As String
HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName ("div")
desc = HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innerText

Sheets(1).Range("K4").Value = desc

'Keep Sheet 1 Open
Sheets(1).Activate

'Delete ESTIMATE Sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets(2).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Error:

End Sub
```

The starting row of the hyperlink is L4, how could I make a loop that cycles through all links located in the L column and runs this script for each hyperlink that is in column L? How would I make a variable to so that Range will know what row is currently being processed?

Could I put my code into something like this:

```
For Each i In Sheet1.Range("L4:L200")

' code here

Next i
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
Sub ImportData()
...
.Open "GET", Range("L4"), False 'Cell that contains hyperlink
...
```

into

```
Sub ImportData(urlToOpen as string)
...
.Open "GET", urlToOpen, False 'Cell that contains hyperlink
...
```

and add a calling procedure:

```
Sub CallRangeL_Urls
    For Each i In Sheet1.Range("L4:L200")
        ' code here
        call ImportData(i)
    Next i
end sub
```

## UPDATE 1

To get data from the procedure you might either send it back into the main procedure or you prepare a place prior to calling the procedure:

either:

```
Sub CallRangeL_Urls
    For Each i In Sheet1.Range("L4:L200")
        ' code here
        call ImportData(i, returnValue)
        i.offset(0,1).value = returnValue
    Next i
end sub

Sub ImportData(urlToOpen as string, returnValue as string)
...
'returnValue = Data you want to give back
returnValue = DataSource...(I didn't read your code again ;-)
...
```

or:

```
Sub CallRangeL_Urls
    Dim targetRange as Range
    For Each i In Sheet1.Range("L4:L200")
        ' code here
        sheets.add after:=sheets(1)

        'set a link on the sheet
        Range("A1").value = i
        Set targetRange = Range("A3")
        call ImportData(i, targetRange)
    Next i
end sub

Sub ImportData(urlToOpen as string, target as range)
...
'Save whatever data to the new sheet
target.offset(0,0).value = datavalue1        'Range("A3")
target.offset(1,0).value = datavalue1        'Range("A4")
target.offset(2,0).value = datavalue1        'Range("A5")
...
```

---

## UPDATE 2

**UPDATE 2: single data items** (working example)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CallRangeL_Urls()
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim returnValue As String

    Set Sheet1 = ActiveSheet

    For Each iCell In Sheet1.Range("L4:L4")
        ' code here
        Debug.Print "url: "; iCell.Value
        Call ImportData(iCell.Value, returnValue)
        iCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = returnValue

        Debug.Print returnValue
    Next iCell
End Sub

Sub ImportData(urlToOpen As String, ByRef returnValue As String)

'...
'returnValue = Data you want to give back
returnValue = "This is the data we get back from yourUrl: " & urlToOpen & " - DATA/DATA/DATA"  'DataSource...(I didn't read your code again ;-)
End Sub
```

**Immediate window:**

```
url: www.google.de
This is the data we get back from yourUrl: www.google.de - DATA/DATA/DATA
```

---

**UPDATE 2: data on result sheet(s) (working example)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CallRangeL_Urls()
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet

    Set Sheet1 = ActiveSheet
    For Each iCell In Sheet1.Range("L4:L4")
        'create a new "RESULTS" sheets
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(1)
        Debug.Print "New sheet created: " & ActiveSheet.Name

        'set a link on the sheet
        Range("A1").Value = iCell.Value     'leave a copy of the url on the sheet as a reference
        Set targetRange = Range("A3")       'here we want to get the results
        Call ImportData(iCell.Value, targetRange)
    Next iCell
End Sub

Sub ImportData(urlToOpen As String, target As Range)
Dim datavalue1, datavalue2, datavalue3
'...
datavalue1 = "data value 1"
datavalue2 = "data value 2"
datavalue3 = "data value 3"

'Save whatever data to the new sheet
target.Offset(0, 0).Value = datavalue1       'Range("A3")
target.Offset(1, 0).Value = datavalue2       'Range("A4")
target.Offset(2, 0).Value = datavalue3       'Range("A5")

Debug.Print "datavalues stored on sheet: " & target.Parent.Name
'...
End Sub
```

**Immediate window:**

```
New sheet created: Sheet2
datavalues stored on sheet: Sheet2
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you so much. Further down the script I have data being inputted to different columns in the row that is being processed, how would I assign the i variable to these? thanks again

Comment: Thanks for your edits, I have more of an idea where you going with this :) however on all of your examples I am getting a 'ByRef argument type mismatch' on Call ImportData(i) when trying to run. Also when calling the the return value would I replace Sheets(1).Range("E4").Value = rng1.Offset(0, 1) with returnValue = rng1.Offset(0, 1)? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry for providing examples with several errors and mistakes. I hope the  "update 2" above clarifies all open questions and give you all the hints you need!